# Z-index into xml for Google maps with custom markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, z-index, google-maps-markers

I am tring to introduce z-index to my map so I can stack custom markers (http://www.ghd.com/global/locations/canada-1/)

I have read there are properties that exist in v3 that allow this to be set. I am wondering in the short term how to create function that means that property can than be specified in my xml for my example above.

I have seen exmaple where it is set in the javascript, but in this example the markers are all set there as well (http://econym.org.uk/gmap/zindex.htm)

I realize this is probably quite a basic solution, I am not that advanced in javascript unfortunately. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your map (and the example you link to) both use the [deprecated Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference), scheduled to be turned off in November, definitely not recommended for new code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/georss.html). This is open source map api. You can use bing,google,openstreet...
But you must known little knowledge javascript.